# How to load a UIWebView when click a button in another view in ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to create an ios application which incuding a UIWebview. I saw so many tutorials that saying how to load webview when start the application. But what I want is when user click on a link in one View,the web page should be loaded in seperate View. This is the code in my button click event.

`

```
 -(IBAction)visitWeb:(id)sender{
         web *wb=[[web alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [self presentModalViewController:wb animated:YES];
     [wb release];}
```

This is in web

`

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {


NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

[super viewDidLoad];  }
```

But it not display anything. Just display the empty `UIWebView` What is the reason for it.plz give me a solution with the code.

Thanks,

Comment: You should be calling [super viewDidLoad] before anything else in  your viewDidLoad().